# In a list of lists, is there a way to convert specific items to the int datatype, the float datatype and the str datatype

Tags: python

For example:

If this were the input:

```
alist = [['hello', '50', '55'], ['Bye', '500.9', '100.6'], ['die', '456', '700.0']]
```

The required output would be:

```
alist = [['hello', 50, 55], ['Bye', 500.9, 100.6], ['die', 456, 700.0]]
```

I tried:

```
for i in alist:
     for j in i:
          try:
             int(j)
          except ValueError:
             try:
                float(j)
             except ValueError:
                str(j)
```

After I ran this and ran `print(alist)`, the same list was printed with no changes whatsoever.

It would be preferable if the answer only used for loops and the int, float and str keywords.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: double `for` loop with multiple `try` `except ValueError`s ?

Comment: I did try this, it didn't really work and I was stumped.

Comment: Sounds like a homework task to me ... is it? What code did you write to accomplish your task? What is your codes problem? [mre] ? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question into something we can help you with.

Comment: "``I did try this``" - how should we know if you don't include the code in your question? "``it didn't really work``" - please be more specific (by updating the question, please don't extend the question's information in the comments).

Comment: It isn't a homework task, more like a miniscule section of a rather large assignment. I haven't copy-pasted from my assignment if that's what you mean. I will edit my question, sorry for not being more precise

Comment: You are using functions  (str(...), int(...), float(...)) that return values. You never do anything with the returned values. Why do you think that your list should change?

Comment: What if I used i = int(i), would it change then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the decimal numbers as floats, this should work just fine. If you have more nested loops, I'd suggest to use a recursive function instead.

```
alist = [['hello', '50', '55'], ['Bye', '500.9', '100.6'], ['die', '456', '700.0']]

for i in range(len(alist)):
    for j in range(len(alist[i])):
        try:
            if "." in alist[i][j]:
                alist[i][j] = float(alist[i][j])
            else:
                alist[i][j] = int(alist[i][j])

        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Alternative with less indexing:

```
for i, out_list in enumerate(alist):
    for j, elem in enumerate(out_list):
        try:
            if "." in elem:
                alist[i][j] = float(elem)
            else:
                alist[i][j] = int(elem)

        except ValueError:
            pass
```

```
>>> alist
[['hello', 50, 55], ['Bye', 500.9, 100.6], ['die', 456, 700.0]]
```

Comment: Side note: lists are iterable, you don't need to iterate over their length. If you need the index, it's usually considered more pythonic to use ``enumerate`` instead.

Comment: yes, but then I wouldn't be able to just replace the element (if I directly enumerate over the `list`s). I could use `enumerate` as you suggested, which would remove some of the indexing. I'll add that

Comment: Thank you so much @Mahrkeenerh , I will use your first solution as I don't fully understand the concept of enumerate yet. :)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#:~:text=enumerate(iterable%2C%20start%3D0)

Answer (score 1):

you should use a try exception keyword.

```
final = []
for ls in alist:
    out = []
    for elem in ls:
        try:
            elem = float(elem)
        except:
            pass
        out.append(elem)
    final.append(out)
```

Comment: you shouldn't use except without argument

Comment: because it hides why the exception is thrown. this makes debugging harder